# Python library for getting information about SVN repository?

Tags: python, svn, svn-repository

I'm searching for a library that can extract (at least) the following information from a SVN repository (*not* a working copy!):

- Revision numbers and their author & commit message
- Changes in each revision (added, deleted, modified files)

Is there a Python library that can do this?

For the authors and commit messages, I could parse "db/revprops/0/..." (simple format), but looking for changed files does not seem so easy, so I'd rather stick with a library that supports SVN repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Python bindings to libsvn: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html.  They facilitate doing pretty much everything the svn command line client can do.

In particular, the [`Client.log()`](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_log) method does what you are looking for.

Comment: `pysvn.Client().log("/var/svn-repos/name-of-repo-directory/")` always gives me the error "pysvn._pysvn_2_6.ClientError: '/var/svn-repos/name-of-repo-directory' is not a working copy". Are we talking about the same definition of "repository"? With repository, I mean the one with "conf", "db", "hooks" subdirectories, not the working copy.

Comment: @AndiDog:  Try `pysvn.Client().log("file:///var/svn-repos/name-of-repo-directory/")`.  That's actually something quite basic in svn:  Plane paths are interpreted as working copies, URIs are interpreted as repositories.  I assumed you to be familiar with this because it also holds for the svn command line client, but I probably should have mentioned it.

Comment: Cool, that works. I didn't know about the difference between URI style and plain paths (-> TortoiseSVN user :P). Thanks for that, I'll try tomorrow if I can extract the relevant information like this.

Comment: Tried it out now, both of my requirements can be met with `pysvn.Client().log("file:///path/to/repo", discover_changed_paths = True)`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want something like [py-svn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html).

Comment: I have already looked into its [programmer's reference](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html) and tested it, but it doesn't seem to be able to read repositories (only WCs). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AndiDog:  You are wrong.  I have updated my answer to give a hint.