# How do I poll the subversion history/log remotely from python?

Tags: python, svn

I need to find the first committer of a branch without having to do a checkout of all the entire branches. 
From command line that is very easy to do:

```
svn log -v --stop-on-copy http://subversion.repository.com/svn/repositoryname
```

I need to do this from a python script, any idea how can I do that? I checked the python subversion bindings but I cannot understand how to do it even if it seemed it can be done.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If there is no way to perform it using python API you can always fall back to svn directly using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: You can use pysvn -- see for example [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471195/python-library-for-getting-information-about-svn-repository/4471312#4471312).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use Python's [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen('svn log -v --stop-on-copy http://subversion.repository.com/svn/repositoryname',
          stdout=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

This way you can run any SVN command you want: just examine `stdout` (and perhaps `stderr`) to get the command's result. You could then use for example a regex to parse the retrieved data:

```
>>> s = Popen('svn log', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> m = re.search('\r\nr(?P<rev>\d+)\s+\|\s+(?P<author>\w+)\s+\|\s+(?P<timestamp>.*?)\s|', s)
{'timestamp': '2011-10-10 10:45:01 +0000 (wed, okt 10 2011)',
 'rev': '1234',
 'author': 'someuser'
}
```

Comment: But be aware that these pipes have somewhat limited buffers and in the case they get filled up you need to read/empty them explicitly. The process will act as it is still running and communicate won't work (it is waiting for the process to end). Docs mention this somewhat vaguely.

Comment: I get this:
    >>> p = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/ls -l')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I also tried adding the stdout parameter and didnt work.

Comment: Do not bother answering :) I started reading the subprocess documentation

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just use a command line call from within Python using the OS package.

```
import os
//cmd = 'ls -l /usr/bin'
cmd = ('svn log -v --stop-on-copy http://subversion.repository.com/svn/repositoryname')

os.system(cmd)
```

Note that this will just make the call, if you want to actually capture the information you need to use Popen from the same OS package.

Comment: This is bad advice.  The `subprocess` module supercedes `os.system()` and has many advantages, including that no shell process is spawned if you don't need it.

Comment: I was just trying to provide something simple, since I know that learning subprocesses and pipes can be intimidating.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron everything helps :)